# headlessui Listbox dropdown menu interfere with the second Listbox

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css, listboxitem, headless-ui

I am having trouble creating dropdown menus using headlessui [Listbox](https://headlessui.com/react/listbox).

There are two listboxes, one at the top and one at the bottom of the page. The problem is that when the top listbox menu is opened, it interferes with the bottom listbox making it difficult to make a selection. The selection menu should be completely front layer. How can I fix this?

Before making selection:

[image: before making selection]

Open the top listbox:

[image: open the top listbox]

The bottom listbox is in the way:

[image: The bottom listbox is in the way]

The code sandbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-react-listbox-example-forked-xyeszm) so you can try test the situation.

Comment: Could you please check the sandbox link? Nothing is there!

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of research, I found a workaround to this problem.

[image: fixed]

We can set the following style option to the first listbox element.
(or make a `div` element that contains the first listbox and set the style.)

```js
style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 1 }}
```

You might not need position option or need to set it to "absolute".

Note that tailwinds "z-1" option didn't work.

The following issue helped me:  https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/discussions/1583

Answer (score 1):

**The parents of the Listboxes that are siblings** need z-indexes that order them correctly.

That is, go up the DOM until the parents of the Listboxes are siblings and add the `z-index:` and `position: relative`. For example:

```
<div>
   <div className="z-50 relative"> {/* Parent of Listbox that is sibling */} 
       <Listbox>...</Listbox>
   </div>
   <div className="z-40 relative"> {/* Parent of Listbox that is sibling */}
       <Listbox>...</Listbox>
   </div>
   <div className="z-30 relative"> {/* Parent of Listbox that is sibling */}
       <Listbox>...</Listbox>
   </div>
</div>
```

That way, you can keep Listbox.Options positioned absolutely and the upper dropdowns will go above the lower dropdowns.

See a fixed version of your Codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-react-listbox-example-forked-yh5jpt?file=/src/Listbox2.js

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired layering without using z-index. In your example, both Listbox options are wrapped by a `<div className="relative">` which is great for the trick I used in this answer.

Since every `position` will create a new position context, the last created one will be on top. Using this information, if we change the order of these two components in their parent and use `flex flex-col-reverse`, visually nothing would change on the screen but Listbox1 options will have a position context created later then Listbox2 options, which in turn makes Listbox1 options appear on top of the the other.

Here is the minimal touch to your example:

```
<div className="flex flex-col-reverse">
  <Listbox2 />
  <Listbox1 />
</div>
```

And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-react-listbox-example-forked-5lmh3z?file=/src/index.js:269-361) is the forked version with the changes above.